# How/when did Claudia figure out who Regina’s father is?

Tags: dark

Warning: Spoilers for Dark Season 3

In Season 3 of the excellent Netflix series *Dark*, Claudia Tiedemann tells Tronte that he is not Regina’s father, so Regina is not a part of the knot.  That is, Regina would exist even if time travel had never been invented, unlike Tronte whose birth was caused by the knot created by time travel.  And indeed, the family tree in the [official Dark website](http://darknetflix.io) shows that in both worlds, Regina is the daughter of Claudia with Bernd Doppler.

But in the family tree in Eve’s headquarters, Tronte is listed as Regina’s father, which I take to mean that Eve erroneously thought that Tronte was the father.  And since alt-Claudia was a loyal follower of Eve, I can only assume that alt-Claudia suffered from the same misconception, since she would have told Eve otherwise.

So my question is, how and when did Claudia figure out that Tronte wasn’t the father?

Comment: Let's not forget that Claudia conceived and gave birth. Just like Hannah knows her child in Adam's world is not Ulrich's but Egon's .. Claudia too would have quite the clear knowledge of who the father to Regina is. It's only a mystery for the audience, not for Claudia.

Comment: I think the issue is that she had multiple affairs at the time, and so it wasn’t initially clear to her who the father was.

Comment: Sure, that was kept from the audience to work the bootstrap paradox angle. But it appears that Claudia always knew that it wasn't Tronte.

Comment: What makes you think Claudia always knew?

Comment: It's that way she tells Tronte in the end. That she always wished he was the father. All I'm saying is there is no evidence that in the same 3 weeks she was sleeping with multiple men. Only in such a case would the mother have a doubt who the father is. The series never goes into the early 2000 life of Claudia.

Comment: @MovieMe I think in that scene she was saying that for a long time she was hoping that Tronte was the father, but then she realized he wasn't.  And I think alt-Claudia never knew the truth, or else she would have tole Eve, which to my mind is further Indication that the main Claudia didn't know either.  And I don't know of any evidence that she did know.

Comment: Any thing to do with Claudia is just endless speculation.

Answer (score 2):

### How?

Mundane means (DNA testing) are possible. Once Claudia got the time-ball from Alt Claudia, it would've been trivial to collect Regina's and all candidate fathers' DNA samples, then go to a time period in which paternity tests are available.

### When?

I don't think when she found this out is particularly important. It took place during the years she spent investigating the true origin of the knot.

### Why?

Which leaves us to the more important question of why she decided to DNA test Regina. We know she was uncertain who Regina's father was. She said to Tronte that for some time she hoped he were the father, which implies lack of certainty.

We also know that at some point Claudia realized some people were of the knot (exist only because time travel exists), but others like herself and Bernd weren't of the knot.

Before all of this, finding out Regina's true father would, at most, be a curiosity to Claudia. After all, paternity tests were already available in the 1980's but Claudia didn't bother, as it wasn't hugely important. However, once she realized some people were knot children, Regina's parentage became hugely important to her strategy. If Bernd's the father, then Regina is not of the knot, and destroying the knot is a viable tactic. If Tronte's the father, however, then Regina *is* of the knot, which means Claudia must seek to maybe change or alter the knot so Regina lives; destroying it (and thus deleting Regina) would be out of the question.